# Java Reflection set enum in model

Tags: java, spring, reflection, enums

I'm trying to update my DTO with Reflection. 
The problem is that some fields in my DTO are *enums* and I get an error that I can not set the *enum* field to *String*.

DTO:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "xxx")
public class Model {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String runId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ExecutionStatus status;


}
```

Controller:

```
 @PatchMapping(path = "/{id}", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> partialUpdateModel(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Map<Object, Object> fields)
        throws Exception {

Optional<Model> model= service.getById(id);

        if (model.isPresent()) {
            fields.forEach((key, value) -> {
                Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(Model.class, (String) key);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                ReflectionUtils.setField(field, model.get(), value);

            });
```

So when it comes to the *enum* field, the field can not be set. It says

> cannot set ExecutionStatus to String

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is this:

```
model.status = "STATUS_1";
// incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to so.A.ExecutionStatus
```

What you apparently want to do is finding the enum constant of the specified enum type with the specified string. That's what the [Enum.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) or `YourEnum.valueOf` method is doing.

Example:

```
enum ExecutionStatus {
    STATUS_1,
    STATUS_2,
}

static class Model {
    public String runId;
    public String name;
    public ExecutionStatus status;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" +
                "runId='" + runId + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", status=" + status +
                '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Object, Object> fields = Map.of(
            "runId", "MyRunId",
            "name", "MyName",
            "status", "STATUS_1"
    );

    Model model = new Model();

    fields.forEach((key, value) -> {
        Field field = null;
        try {
            field = Model.class.getDeclaredField((String) key);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.getType().isEnum()) {
                // First variant (YourEnum.valueOf(String)
                Method valueOf = field.getType().getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
                Object enumConstant = valueOf.invoke(null, value);
                field.set(model, enumConstant);

                // Alternative (Enum.valueOf(Class, String) (cast is safe due to isEnum)
                field.set(model, Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) field.getType(), (String) value));
            } else {
                field.set(model, value);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    System.out.println(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, Also understand reflection is costly it involves types that are being dynamically resolved, i'd recommend writing setters or constructor instead

```
   if ("ExecutionStatus".equalsIgnoreCase(field.getType().getSimpleName())) {
                ReflectionUtils.setField(field, model.get(), ExecutionStatus.valueOf(value));
     } else {
                ReflectionUtils.setField(field, model.get(), value);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your source map is of type `<Object, Object>`

What you try to do is to set a field of type `ExecutionStatus` reading a value of type `Object`. Types on your fields must match. First convert a value to `ExecutionStatus` then use the method `.setField(..)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution! Please make use of the markdown ability when posting an answer to make it easier to read through your response.